# Asymmetrical collection view layout with cells paired or solo

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I was spending a long time trying to accomplish this without any ideas.
I have this data model, which I need to put into a collection view.
The main problem is that collection views are not that elastic.

[image]

The data model can be in a different structure similar to this, and is not symmetrical. It can be in any other order **but it always go down**. the only difference is the side in which the index goes.

**I have tried :**

1. Creating sections in which each section gets 2 cells, then when creating the layout I had a problem where a single cell in a section must be on the right side, and the next on the left. but the delegate's order is the opposite, and you get into complications of moving cells around.
2. Inserting a cell to a specific index, so I can set a section with 2 indexes and then insert the cell to index **1** directly and not to 0 . (this is impossible because the max index should be maximum the `data.count` )

Should I just build it by myself? Are these things possible with a collection view at all?

Comment: What did you try in your custom `UICollectionViewLayout`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant as in code samples

Comment: The code samples are long and dirty after hours of experiments. I guess people here knows better then me if its possible at all and how.

Comment: If you can't get this to work by modifying a flow layout, you can most certainly [write your own layout object](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/). Sticking with the flow layout, though, off the top of my head, this would make more sense to me as two columns than rows of two cells.

Comment: Did you override `func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(_ rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?`?

Comment: Can you explain the criteria for deciding whether the next cell goes on the right or left?

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, its completely random and depends on a user flow and how he choose to build it. This is why I can't find any structure to put into a formula. But I do have some array that contains data regarding the placement of every cell . What I could learn is that the order of a collection view is not something you can manipulate. You can not insert cell at specific future index, or to move them around in the delegates.